# How to multiply only one row in a query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT user_id, currency, SUM( price ) AS totalPrice, created
FROM accounts WHERE user_id IN ( SELECT users.id FROM users
                                 WHERE country_id ='$con_id' )
AND created BETWEEN  '2013-02-01' AND  '2013-02-28' GROUP BY currency
```

This query give me result like

```
Curreny  totalPrice
SEK      10
USD      10
```

I want to multiply only **SEK** from 7. I have only **USD** rate in the database, so i want to multiply it in the query with **7** to get **SEK** rate. How can I do that in this query?

Comment: What do you mean by this because I'm a little bit confused? *I want to multiply only SEK from 7. I have only USD rate in the database, so i want to multiply it in the query with 7 to get SEK rate.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little bit confusing. If I understand your question correctly, you want to multiply the value of total value by `7` if the currency is equal to `SEK`.

```
SELECT  user_id, 
        currency, 
        SUM(price) * IF(currency = 'SEK', 7, 1) totalPrice, 
        created
FROM    accounts
WHERE   user_id
        IN 
        (
            SELECT users.id
            FROM users
            WHERE country_id =  '$con_id'
        ) AND 
        created BETWEEN  '2013-02-01' AND  '2013-02-28'
GROUP   BY currency
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store all conversion rates in a table. For SEK you store 7.0 als conversion rate and vor USD 1.0. Simply multiplie the totalPrice with the conversion rate (with sub query)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly way to implement it:

```
SELECT user_id, currency,
       CASE WHEN currency = 'SEK' THEN SUM(price)*7
       ELSE SUM(price) END totalPrice, created
FROM accounts
WHERE user_id
IN ( SELECT users.id FROM users
     WHERE country_id =  '$con_id')
AND created BETWEEN  '2013-02-01' AND  '2013-02-28'
GROUP BY currency
```